# Maximize Payout & Keep Cost Below X

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem, minimize, maximize

Lets say I have 100 nodes each consisting of (payout, cost)

Is there an algorithm to find X nodes that produce the most payout without cost going above Y amount?

I'm not sure if there's a simple sorting algorithm or somehow make a weighted tree out of it. Or is brute forcing it the only approach?

**Example**:
We want best payout from 3 nodes without going over 20 cost

Nodes[] = (10, 8), (7, 8), (6, 7), (5, 3), (11, 14)

*Best Result*: (10, 8), (7, 8), (5, 3)
Payout = 22
Cost = 19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a famous problem called the [0/1 knapsack problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), and there are a ton of approaches you can use for solving it. The easiest - and one of the most efficient - solutions is a dynamic programming algorithm that considers the elements one at a time. With that term in mind, I think you should be able to find some great resources here on Stack Overflow or more broadly across the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Integer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) to solve the problem. Here's a complete solution in Python using PuLP library:

```
import pulp

# Input parameters
nodes = [(10, 8), (7, 8), (6, 7), (5, 3), (11, 14)]

# Cost limit
max_cost = 20

# Create an LP problem object with maximization objective
problem = pulp.LpProblem("Knapsack", pulp.LpMaximize)

# Define decision variables
choices = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("choice", range(len(nodes)), lowBound = 0, upBound = 1, cat = pulp.LpInteger)

# Define optimization function (sum of payoffs)
problem += sum([nodes[i][0] * choices[i] for i in range(len(nodes))])

# Add cost constraint (sum of costs below max_cost)
problem += sum([nodes[i][1] * choices[i] for i in range(len(nodes))]) <= max_cost, "CostConstraint"

# Solve the problem
problem.solve()

# Print the solution
solution = [int(choices[i].value()) for i in range(len(nodes))] 
print(solution)
```

The code prints:

```
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```